# How to display recent(latest post) as the first on a list of a blog

Tags: php, html

Hello everyone I need your help on the php code below.
I am trying to display recent(latest post) as the first on a list. I don't know how to use ORDER BY timestamp Please help.
Here is my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
   <?php
   include_once('includes/connection.php');
   include_once('includes/article.php');

   $article = new Article;
   $articles = $article->fetch_all();
   ?>

   <html>
   <head>
    <title>Blogger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.php" id="logo">B</a>

        <ol>
            <?php foreach ($articles as $article){?>
            <li><a href="article.php?id=<?php echo 
             $article['article_id'];>">
            <?php echo $article['article_title'];?>
            </a> 
            - <small>
            popsted <?php echo date('l jS', $article['article_timestamp']);>
            </small>
            </li>
            <?php }?>
        </ol>

        <small><a href="admin">Admin</a></small>
    </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Below is my Article class code, please help me on how to place/insert the ORDER BY timestamp query. Thank you!

```
<?php

class Article{
    public function fetch_all(){
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles");
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();
    }

        public function fetch_data($article_id){
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $article_id);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: You need to add this to your SQL query...  `ORDER BY article_timestamp DESC`.  I have no idea how you should add it since we don't know what your class `Article` looks like.  Btw, you're not closing the PHP-block after you echo the `article_id`.

Comment: Edit your _question_ instead of posting code in comments. As you can see, it's pretty unreadable in this format. I've also already given you a hint on how to do it so try it.

Comment: Yes Magnus, I have tried on the hint you gave me but it wouldn't work. Please help. I have added the "Article class" code .Thanks!

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_timestamp DESC"`. That's if `article_timestamp` is the date you want to order it by.

Comment: Thanks Magnus...will try that one.

Comment: Thanks buddy it worked!

Comment: I added an answer. You can accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ORDER BY` to your SQL-query:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_timestamp DESC");
```

The above tells MySQL to order the results by the `article_timestamp` column in a DESCending order. If you want the oldest first, it's `ASC` as in ASCending.

You can [read more in the manual about sorting columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html).